# Why not does android provide a static applicationContext? In that case, many properties can be declared staticly

Tags: android, applicationcontext

If I provide it in this way, is there any hidden problem?

```
lateinit var AppContext: Context
    private set

class MainApplication : Application(){
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AppContext = this.applicationContext
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's not really static, logically speaking (maybe almost-static). Notice that there is small time window, in which the `AppContext` object is null (from process start until `onCreate` is called).

Comment: But in this static case, everything needing appcontext runs well. And therefore so many things relying on appcontext can be static fields too, like database, dao and so many related utils. We don't need hilt to build and inject these static objects.

Comment: Well, I tend to agree, even though it's not initialized statically (only after application's `onCreate`). I'll follow to hear more insights